# PHP POST/GET value of checkbox into url in this format

Tags: php, arrays, json, post, get

PHP POST/GET value of checkbox into url in this format

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
```

hey, guys how to convert value of checked checkbox like this

when i submit the button

```
example.com?value = [1,2,3]
```

i have to convert like [1,2,3] cause i need to store it in API JSON
is that like array or what? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure these are checkboxes? When you have added the code of `select` tag.

Comment: what are you talking about a checkbox or select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your submit button handler:

```
ev.preventDefault();
ev.stopPropagation();
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
  values.push(checked[i].value);
}

window.location = "example.com?values=["+values.join(",")+"]";
```